# How does this if-else statement inside a function work?

Tags: javascript

I've been completing challenges on FreeCodeCamp and stumbled upon this solution for an algorithm. Can't comprehend how the if else statement works here.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

  var temp = [];
  var result = [];

  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if (a % size !== size - 1)
      temp.push(arr[a]);
    else {
      temp.push(arr[a]);
      result.push(temp);
      temp = [];
    }
  }

  if (temp.length !== 0)
    result.push(temp);

  return result;
}
```

Why is `temp = []` at the end of the `else` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function divides an array into chunks of small arrays where the 'size' parameter defines the length of each chunks array. 
The algorithm works as follows:

- iterate each array element (for loop) until main_array elements index
  is less than chunk array size (a % size !== size - 1), and push elements into 
  temporary array.
- else block - push element into temp array, push temp array into results array 
  and create new empty temp array ();

  at the end if temp array length is not 0 then push it also into results array.
  that's it :)

Answer (score 6):

`temp = []` means "reset the `temp` variable to an empty array"

---

in the if block, the `arr[a]` element is pushed at the end in the `temp`array.

in the else block, the same happens AND the whole current `temp` array is added at the end of the big `result` array of arrays, and the `temp`array is reset to the empty array.

Cannot say much more since there is not data or context written in your question. Hope this has answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the code tries to divide an array into chunks of smaller arrays of size `size`. Let's say you have a big bag full of apples and you want to reduce it to smaller apple bags each having at max 2 apples. How would you do in real life?  You will go through the apples starting from first one and keep putting them in a small bag until it gets full. Then you move to **another** small bag and start to fill that it. Same thing is done here.

Inside `if` there is a condition checking if the temporary chunks have been filled and if not then keep pushing to the current temporary array. If yes then create a new array and keep pushing to it. `temp=[]` ensures the resetting.

Comment: Funny pseudo, but notice that we check if 1 last apple fits, if so, put it in the bag and grab a new bag. At the end we check if our last bag isn't empty and also put it in the results. For example, if we divide 9 apples is bags of 2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

It happens @Peter Pavluchenko. Let's walk through the code and see what it's doing.

the caller is specifying the size of chunks.

- a % size !== size -1

  - % is a mod operator. so when a is divided by size what is the result? is the result not equal to size -1?

if the result of 'a' being divided by size is not equal to size -1, than we push the item to the end of our temp array.

If the result of 'a' being divided by size is equal to size - 1, we have found our first chunk! So lets' add the item to our temp array and add the temp array to our result array.

temp array
- item 1
- item 2

result array
- item
-- item 1
-- item 2

so when you do result[0], you will get another array.

chunk = result[0];
chunk[0] = the actual object you might be interested in.

After we have pushed the temp array to the end of our result array, we need to reset it so we can start collecting items for the next chunk.

The last 'if' is looking for situations like, you are in the middle of a chunk, but it's not a whole chunk as specified by the size argument. so we have some objects in our temp array that we need to add to the result array before we leave the method.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the task is to split up a given array (`arr`) into an array of arrays, of which each array has length `size` - except perhaps for the last which has any "leftovers" if the length of `array` is not an exact multiple of `size`.

The way the given solution works is to go through `arr`, pushing its elements into the temporary array `temp`. But every `size` steps - this corresponds to the `else` condition inside the `for` loop - the `temp` array will have the correct length (namely `size`), so then the entire `temp` array, as a single element, is appended to the `result` array, and then returned to being an empty array to start over.

This way, `result` ends up with the chunks of size `size` as required. The final `if` statement just adds the "leftovers" on - that is, anything left in `temp`. (But we check that it isn't empty, otherwise if the length was an exact multiple you'd have an unwated empty array at the end of `result`.)